# How can I clear the database entries for a specific object?

Tags: apex, custom-object, delete

I added a custom object and some fields. I also added several entries to the database for this object. Can I delete certain entries or all of them at once that relate to my object in some predefined way, or do I need to write my own code for this?

Comment: You can import the data and then mark the field value as null and update them again using data loader

Comment: You can go into more detail. I'm a newbie and I don't understand what exactly it is about?

Comment: check out this module on trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_implementation_data_management 

In your case you can Export data first then update the data instead of Import.

Comment: If you want to delete all records, you could check the truncate option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue like this: I went to the developer console in the upper-right corner of the web browser. I clicked **Debug** > **Run Anonymous Apex**:

```
List<Exchange_Rate__c> listDelete = [select Id From Exchange_Rate__c];
delete listDelete;
```

Answer (score 1):

##### To clear out the every record in the Custom Sobject

`delete [select Id From Custom_Sobject__c];`

##### > Can I delete certain entries or all of them at once that relate to my object in some predefined way

If your custom object has a master-detail field (is the detail/child in this relationship), when the parent is deleted, the child will be deleted automatically. It's called `cascade delete`.

Apparently, cascade delete could be enabled in lookup too but I haven't used it yet. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313755&type=1&mode=1

##### if none of the above suits you

You will need to write a trigger to handle the cascade delete.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by two way:

1. Use data loader/workbench to export the ids of the records and use the delete operation of DL/workbench to delete them.
2. Create a batch apex, which queries all records in the start method. In executing method add them to list and delete the records. Run the batch suing dev console. This ensures that you don't run into any governor limits.